# Collision detection not working in 2d android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making a small side 2d scrolling game and for some reason my collision detection is not working. I can't figure it out I have been trying to fix it for a couple days but nothing seems to work. Can you help me! Thanks in advance!!!!

```
public class GameScreen extends Screen {
enum GameState {
    Ready, Running, Paused, GameOver
}

static GameState state = GameState.Ready;
// Variable Setup
// You would create game objects here.
public Paint paint, paint2;
public static int gameHeight = AndroidGame.height;
public static int gameWidth = AndroidGame.width;
public static int byX = SampleGame.x;
public static int byY = SampleGame.y;
public static int x = 60;
public static int y = AndroidGame.height - 80;
public static int surface = AndroidGame.height - 80;
public static int numberSq = 25;
public static int[] values;
public double counter2 = 4;
public int counterStep;
public Image person;
public static Image[] walk = new Image[9];
public static Image object;
private Animation anim;
public static int up = 0;
public static int right = 0;
public long jumpTime = 200;
public static Rect[] valuesSq;
public static Rect[] valuesSq2;
public static Rect[] valuesSq3;
public static Rect rectOne;
public static Rect rectTwo;
public int colide = 0;
public static boolean boolResult;
private Collision collision;

public GameScreen(Game game) {
    super(game);

    rectOne = new Rect(x, y, 27, 75);
    valuesSq = new Rect[numberSq];
    valuesSq2 = new Rect[numberSq];
    valuesSq3 = new Rect[numberSq];

    values = new int[numberSq];
    values[0] = 300;
    for (int i = 1; i < numberSq; i++) {
        values[i] = (values[i - 1] + 200);

    }

    object = Assets.object;
    walk[1] = Assets.walk[1];
    walk[2] = Assets.walk[2];
    walk[3] = Assets.walk[3];
    walk[4] = Assets.walk[4];
    walk[5] = Assets.walk[5];
    walk[6] = Assets.walk[6];
    walk[7] = Assets.walk[7];
    walk[8] = Assets.walk[8];

    anim = new Animation();
    anim.addFrame(walk[1], 50);
    anim.addFrame(walk[2], 50);
    anim.addFrame(walk[3], 50);
    anim.addFrame(walk[4], 50);
    anim.addFrame(walk[5], 50);
    anim.addFrame(walk[6], 50);
    anim.addFrame(walk[7], 50);
    anim.addFrame(walk[8], 50);
    person = anim.getImage();

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(30);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    paint2 = new Paint();
    paint2.setTextSize(30);
    paint2.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);

}

@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {
    List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();



    if (state == GameState.Ready)
        updateReady(touchEvents);
    if (state == GameState.Running)
        updateRunning(touchEvents, deltaTime);
    if (state == GameState.Paused)
        updatePaused(touchEvents);
    if (state == GameState.GameOver)
        updateGameOver(touchEvents);
}

private void updateReady(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {

    // This example starts with a "Ready" screen.
    // When the user touches the screen, the game begins.
    // state now becomes GameState.Running.
    // Now the updateRunning() method will be called!

    if (touchEvents.size() > 0) {
        state = GameState.Running;
    }
}

private void updateRunning(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents, float deltaTime) {
    // This is identical to the update() method from our Unit 2/3 game.
    // x++;

    right = 1;
    if (right == 1) {

        for (int i = 0; i < numberSq; i++) {
            values[i] -= 4;
        }
    }

    // 1. All touch input is handled here:
    int len = touchEvents.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);

        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {

            if (event.x < 640) {
                // Move left.
            }

            else if (event.x > 640) {
                // Move right.
            }

        }

        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP && y == surface) {
            up = 1;
            new Thread(new thread()).start();

        }

        else if (event.x > 640) {
            // Stop moving right. }

        }
    }
    if (y < surface) {
        y += 6;
    }
    if (y > surface) {
        y = surface;
    }
    if (up == 1) {
        // Stop moving left.
        counter2 = 4;
        counter2 += .1;
        y = y + (int) ((Math.sin(counter2) + Math.cos(counter2)) * 14.2);
        if (counter2 >= 10) {
            counter2 = 4;
        }
    }

    person = anim.getImage();

    animate();

}

private void updatePaused(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {
    int len = touchEvents.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {

        }
    }
}

private void updateGameOver(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {

    int len = touchEvents.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
            if (event.x > 300 && event.x < 980 && event.y > 100
                    && event.y < 500) {
                nullify();
                game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void paint(float deltaTime) {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    // g.drawImage(Assets.background, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberSq; i++) {
        valuesSq[0 + i] = new Rect(values[0 + i] - 6, surface - 35, 1,
                110);
        valuesSq2[0 + i] = new Rect(values[0 + i] - 6, 0, 1, 110);
        if (Rect.intersects(rectOne,valuesSq[0 + i])
                || Rect.intersects(rectOne,valuesSq2[0 + i])) {
            state=GameState.GameOver;
                    } else {
                }
            }
    g.drawRect(0, 0, gameWidth, gameHeight, Color.CYAN);
    g.drawRect(x, y, 27, 75, Color.BLACK);
    g.drawImage(person, x, y);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberSq; i++) {
        g.drawImage(object, values[0 + i] - 6, surface - 35);
        g.drawImage(object, values[0 + i] - 6, 0);
    }
    g.drawString("" + boolResult, 320, 480, paint);

    // Secondly, draw the UI above the game elements.
    if (state == GameState.Ready)
        drawReadyUI();
    if (state == GameState.Running)
        drawRunningUI();
    if (state == GameState.Paused)
        drawPausedUI();
    if (state == GameState.GameOver)
        drawGameOverUI();

}

private void nullify() {

    paint = null;

    System.gc();
}

private void drawReadyUI() {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

    g.drawARGB(155, 0, 0, 0);
    g.drawString("Tap each side of the screen to move in that direction.",
            320, 480, paint);

}

private void drawRunningUI() {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();


}

private void drawPausedUI() {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    g.drawARGB(155, 0, 0, 0);
    g.drawString("Resume", 400, 165, paint2);
    g.drawString("Menu", 400, 360, paint2);

}

private void drawGameOverUI() {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 320, 480, Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("GAME OVER.", 50, 50, paint);

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    if (state == GameState.Running)
        state = GameState.Paused;

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}

@Override
public void backButton() {
    pause();
}

public void animate() {
    anim.update(10);
}

public class thread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(jumpTime);
            up = 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            new Thread(this).start();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Quick glance, but I don't see where you're handling any collisions with anything... You're not even using your `collision` object... What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: What? I am using the rectangles, to see if they collision occurs that changes the state to game over.

Comment: Ahh. In the paint method, where you're checking if rectOne intersects with those squares you generate.

Comment: It seems like your `rectOne` is initialized with an x range of 60 to 27. That's a problem because 'left' should be less than 'right' and the same issue occurs with your `valueSq`s... But also, even if the order were correct it seems like values[i] is equal to (i * 200) + 300... Which is very far off from where your rectOne should be...

Comment: Were does it say my x has a range? My x is the x coordinate for my character.

Comment: For the rects you're using for collision. You instantiate them with four points: left, top, right, bottom. I meant the x ranges for those rects...

Comment: for those rects I use (x cord, y cord, width, height)

Comment: Are you using `android.graphics.Rect`?

Comment: Rect's parameters aren't `Rect(x, y, width, height)`, they're `Rect(left, top, right, bottom)`, so for your purposes you may want to use `Rect(x, y, x + width, y - height)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rect`'s parameters aren't `Rect(x, y, width, height)`, they're `Rect(left, top, right, bottom)`, so for your purposes you may want to use `Rect(x, y, x + width, y - height)`.